# JavaScript: For loop continues until end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm making a practice webpage with a list of guitars. What I want to do is when a thumbnail for the guitar Fender Telecaster is clicked, a for-loop runs through all the images with a class name of "gallery", takes that information and places it on various different parts of the DOM. Important things to know:

-- The thumbnails of these guitars all have class names of "gallery," and I have five guitars in this order: Fender Stratocaster, Fender Telecaster, Gibson Les Paul, Gibson SG, Gretsch Electromatic.

-- Each has a title which corresponds to the name of the guitar AND the file name of the various images related to the guitar (for example, the title "gibson-les-paul" and the image files are "gibson-les-paul.jpg" and "gibson-les-paul-big.jpg")

-- Each image thumbnail has four data attributes which JavaScript takes and places on the DOM.

THE PROBLEM: The for-loop works fine EXCEPT when I click any of the thumbnails the last image with a class of "gallery" (Gretsch Electromatic) and all of its information appears in the DOM. So if I click on any of the five, it takes information from the last element in the loop.

The first bit of code I have included just so the rest makes sense. It's the second bit of code I have trouble with:

```
function replaceNodeText(id, newText) {
    var node = document.getElementById(id);
    while (node.firstChild)
      node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
    node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newText));
  } 

var gallery = "gallery";
var images = "images/";
var big = "-big.jpg";
```

// Above is all fine and good, it's below where the issue is:

```
function bigChange() { 
    var runThrough = document.getElementsByClassName(gallery);
    for (var i = 0; i < runThrough.length; i++) {
        var dataKey1 = runThrough[i].getAttribute("data-key1");     
        var dataKey2 = runThrough[i].getAttribute("data-key2"); 
        var dataKey3 = runThrough[i].getAttribute("data-key3");     
        var dataKey4 = runThrough[i].getAttribute("data-key4");
        var title = runThrough[i].getAttribute("title");


        document.getElementById("popUpPic").src = images + title + big;

        if (title != "fender-telecaster") {
            document.getElementById("photo_large").src = images + title + ".jpg";
            }
        else {
            document.getElementById("photo_large").src = images + title + ".png";
            }
        replaceNodeText("guitarTitle", dataKey1);
        replaceNodeText("guitarBrand", dataKey2);
        replaceNodeText("caption1", dataKey3); 
        replaceNodeText("guitarPrice", dataKey4);


        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

:-)

Comment: You should focus on the "title" attribute and how it controls the logic of your code.  Doesn't that represent the brand you clicked on (assuming class "gallery" elements are being clicked)?  Instead of a loop it appears `bigChange()` would actually be something like `onGuitarSelected(guitarType)` with no loop inside of it.

Comment: I'll change the name from bigChange to onGuitarSelected(guitarType) just for the sake of clarity, got it.

Other than that, I'll work on changing it from a for loop to something more like what you suggested to see if it works, but if anyone else has any pointers I'm all ears. Thank you veritasetratio.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `break` in your if/else statement so that it doesn't loop through all of the pictures

Comment: I tried putting break; in the if/else statement, as well as after the four replaceNodeText statements and after the second-to-last curly bracket. It just stops the loop all-together. It needs something else.